# How to increase power of a wireless power transmitter circuit?

Tags: wireless, oscillator, multisim, resonance

[image: Circuit simulation multisim 13.0]

I designed this circuit for a frequency of 2MHz, but I get an output of 7mW. I need to increase the output power up to at least 10 to 20W. Help me to redesign the circuit. Consider the transformer T1 (not an actual transformer, just two inductor coils) is a combination of transmitter and receiver. The primary is the Tx and secondary is the Rx, and there would be a distance of one meter between primary and secondary. A minimum output of 5W is needed in the receiver side (at the secondary). The transformer inductance is 10uH.

Comment: I don't know if you are actually using 1n4007 diodes at the receive side but those are not an appropriate choice.

Comment: Wait,what? you need **5W at the secondary** with a **gap between pri and sec of a metre**? How much power are you generating at the primary? Also, when you say "transformer inductance" is that the primary inductance or the leakage inductance? If it's the primary inductance, what do you measure as the leakage inductance?

Comment: then Suggest me right diode. @DwayneReid

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment, 1N4007 diodes are useless at this frequency. All silicon diodes have what is known as "reverse recovery time". When a diode goes from forward conducting to reverse blocking there is a period of time that the diode will conduct during voltage reversal. A lot of diodes are sub 100ns but the 1N400x range is 30 us. Given that you are switching at 2 MHz and this has a period of 500 ns, the 1N400x will never work as a rectifier.

Also ensure that your secondary tuning capacitor is the correct value to make the secondary resonate.

Comment: @BrianDrummond power in Transmitter circuit is 20 watts.i kept the transformer inductance as 10uH for both primary and secondary. and the leakage inductance is 0H(zero).

Comment: @Quadphazer if the coils are loosely coupled then the leakage inductance IS NOT zero. If primary and secondary inductance is the same then the primary (or secondary) tuning capacitance is wrong by inspection.